# How to access in a child component an array's properties in React Redux?

Tags: arrays, properties, react-redux

I am unable to access an array's properties in React Redux, in a child component. I can log the array and the filtered array but not the array's properties. It states: 'Type Error: The property of director is 'undefined''. How can I access the properties?

```
export class DirectorView extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
  }
  render() {
    const { director, movies } = this.props;
    console.log(movies); // works, all movies are logged
    console.log(director); // works, director is logged

    if (!director) return null;
    const directorMovies = movies.filter(m => m.director.name == director);
    console.log(directorMovies); // works, all movies of director are logged
    console.log(directorMovies[0]) // works, the first movie of the array is displayed
    // following do not work! All TypeError: Cannot read property 'director' of undefined
    //console.log(directorMovies[0]['director'].title)
    //console.log(directorMovies[0].director.title)
    //console.log(directorMovies[0][director][name])

    return (
      <Card bg="light" style={{ width: '90%' }}>
        <Card.Body>
          <Card.Title>{director}</Card.Title>
          <Card.Title>name: {director.name}</Card.Title>
```

Answer (score 1):

It seems that your: 
`directorMovies[0].director.title`
is different from:
`directorMovies[0].director.name`, which is the one used to filter your array.

You can try to log your `director` object to understand what's going on:

```
console.log(directorMovies[0].director)
```